How can i setup GTK for Rust in Windows?
I have tried to use GTK4 on Linux Mint with Rust and it works. I want to do the same on Windows with Visual Studio Tools and it doesn't allow me, I tried with GNU and MSYS and it doesn't work either. Then I tried to compile for Windows from Linux and it also gives error.
I did the installation of programs and dependencies that said in the guides but always gives me errors that some GTK libraries are not found in the MINGW.
Sincerely, I do not understand what to do, any information that can help is greatly appreciated and of course, thank you!
sudo apt install gcc-mingw-w64-x84-64
export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
cargo build --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu

And nothing happens, it gives me these errors:
note: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgtk-3: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgdk-3: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -latk-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgdk-3: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo: No such file or directory
…


Have you followed the instructions?

@eggyal Yep, I chose the third option, installed everything needed, downloaded MSYS and ran the command that says in the guide, set the environment variables in "Path" (in the box above which I think I remember is the user) and then "rustup toolchain install stable-gnu" & "rustup default stable-gnu".

The instructions you linked are for GTK4, but the error messages you posted hint that your code is trying to use GTK3. Please share your Cargo.toml and a minimal main.rs that exhibits the problem.

@Jmb You are right, I thought that 0.4 refers to GTK version 4, I will try with gtk4 to see how it works. The Cargo.toml was the following one: [dependencies].
gtk = "0.4.1"

@Jmb Great! That was it, I uninstalled GTK4 from MSYS and installed GTK3 and it worked! Although it looks horrible haha, in Linux Mint it looked nicer. That might have something to do with the version (GTK3/4). I also tried to make a "Hello World" with the tutorial on the guide site and it gives me code errors :/
But well, I'm already raving, thank you very much!
